# Sculpting around corners causing weird pinching

Tags: sculpting

Why does this happen whenever sculpting around corners? I can never get it to smooth out or crease smoothly without this weird pinching on the corners. Im working with 3 million polys and it still gives the same result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some normals got flipped, that always results in strange pinching. In edit mode, select the object and then press the "Shift + N" key combination to recalculate the normals. You can also use the menu as an alternative: In Edit mode, select the object, and then go to Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside.

Here is a [nice explanation of the problem](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/#:%7E:text=In%20Edit%20Mode%2C%20select%20the%20object%2C%20then%20hit%20%E2%80%9CShift,%3E%20Normals%20%3E%20Recalculate%20Outside%E2%80%9D.)

If this doesn't fix it, maybe have a look at your object in wireframe mode.
Maybe vertices got way too twisted by too much sculpting operations. If the smoothing brushes cant't fix this, then maybe you should try to fix this in Edit mode